# SELECT COUNT(0) on big table is slow

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
SELECT COUNT(0) FROM ts_client
LEFT JOIN ts_shop_client ON shop_client_id_client = client_id
WHERE client_email IS NOT NULL AND shop_client_id_shop = 1
```

Explain:
[image]

Rows in ts_client is 4904908, Rows in ts_shop_client is 3547939.

I have properly set up indexes and sql is slow time is 5,49 - 9,50s.

Hello guys.

Anyone solution to speed sql ?

Table ts_client

[image]

Table ts_shop_client

[image]

Indexes ts_shop_client

[image]
Thanks

Comment: have you tried: SELECT COUNT(0) FROM ts_client
LEFT JOIN ts_shop_client ON shop_client_id_client = client_id
and client_email IS NOT NULL AND shop_client_id_shop = 1

Comment: I assume that `client_email` is on the `ts_client` table and `shop_client_id_shop` is on the `ts_shop_client` table. Do you realise that including a column from the outer-joined table in the `where` clause turns an outer join back into an inner join? Is this what you want?

Comment: @Balinti: That would almost certainly return a different result.

Comment: Did you try [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) that query?

Comment: You're doing a full table scan on a table with 5.5 million records and that's why it's slow - it performs seeks on your (slow) hard disk. Since your query can't utilize indexes (properly) since those indexes (if they were set) would have low selectivity, the best way is to convert both tables to InnoDB and raise `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to an amount that can house both tables in memory. That will turn your I/O from disk to RAM, which is several thousands of times faster.

Comment: Have you tried running the query with the "Include Actual Execution Plan" on? Verify your indexes are being used and identify the potential bottlenecks there.

Comment: "I have properly set up indexes" -- show us.

Comment: Balinti - code is better, but still slow 3 - 5s ...

Comment: @Mjh - this is solution, nice work!!! Can you your comment to the answer ?. ;) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
INDEX(shop_client_id_client, shop_client_id_shop) -- in either order.
```

Such an index will narrow down the number of rows you need to look at.  This speeds things up.

Before, it had to read, then skip, each rows where `shop_client_id_shop` was not 1.

Comment: Some explanation of the implications of adding the index, both for solving the issue and for any downsides/tradeoffs, would improve this one-liner as an answer.

Comment: Not solve my problem, i added indexes screen to my question, please see it

Comment: Two separate indexes on two fields is **NOT** the same as a composite index on the two fields.  Please try the `INDEX` I suggested.

Comment: @RickJames:  It looks to me like the first index in the screen shot is the one you asked for.